# DevExpress edit template combobox value to parameter

Tags: devexpress

I have two pre populated combo boxes with `value` = “ID” and `Text` = Relevant data...

I am doing an edit in a grid view and I adjusted the template to have the two combo boxes (each relevant field has its own).

I have searched high and low and I assume this is so easy people don’t even ask about it... but if you see below the combo boxes do not populate the parameters with the value of the combo boxes.

So I have tried this:

```
    protected void aspxGridviewUsers_RowUpdating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.NewValues["StoreID"] = GetStoreID();
        e.NewValues["GroupID"] = GetGroupID();

    }
    protected int GetStoreID()
    {
        ASPxComboBox CBID = new ASPxComboBox();
        CBID = aspxGridviewUsers.FindEditFormTemplateControl("ASPxComboBoxStoreEdit") as ASPxComboBox;
        return Convert.ToInt32(CBID.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
    }
    protected int GetGroupID()
    {
        ASPxComboBox CBID = new ASPxComboBox();
        CBID = aspxGridviewUsers.FindEditFormTemplateControl("ASPxComboBoxGroupEdit") as ASPxComboBox;
        return Convert.ToInt32(CBID.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
    }
```

This did not work. What am I doing wrong here?

How can I use those values in the comboboxes to update against my update statement?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the following code:

return Convert.ToInt32(CBID.Value);

code.  Does it work for you?